# Rails 3.2 Resources and url_option()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have successfully established a link between the models and photo albums. The next step I added a user model and established a connection with the same models. It works, users can create albums and upload photos, but if Paul wants to put user link to the album, it is desirable that it looked like this in `mysite.com/user/1/albums/1`
In routes.rb I added the following code

```
resources :users do
  resources :albums do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

The code to add the image in the template is an album (albums / show.html.erb). After I added the resource: user I get an error

```
undefined method `album_photos_path'
```

with reference to this ruby line

```
<H1>ADD NEW IMAGE</H1>
    <%= form_for [@album, @photo], :html => {:multipart => true} do |form| %>
```

I was advised to apply url_option but I could not figure out how it works.

def create in PhotosController

```
def create
  @photo = @album.photos.new(params[:photo])
  @photo.user_id = current_user.id
  if @photo.save
    flash[:notice] = "Photo created!"
    redirect_to album_url(@album)
  else
    flash[:notice] = "No created"
    redirect_to album_url(@album)
  end
end
```

there is an elegant solution to my problem?

Comment: see what `rake routes` outputs for that path, it might be `users_photos_albums_path`. Or use `form_for [@user, @album, @path]`

Comment: @mihai if I use `[@user, @album, @path]` i see `undefined method model_name for NilClass:Class`

rake routes  

`user_album_photos GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:album_id/photos`

but I do not know how to point to an object @user in this case :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on you're comment, it seems like you need this:

```
<%= form_for user_album_photos_path(@user, @album, @photo), :html => {:multipart => true} do |form| %>
```

And in the controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  if @user.id != current_user.id
    # display some error and redirect
  end
  @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:album_id])
  @photo = @album.photos.new(params[:photo])
  ...
end
```